# Aligning Decimal when convert int to string

Tags: java, string, alignment, int, decimal

I understand that in Java you can use printf such as

```
System.out.printf("check1 =  " + "%11.5f  percent\n", 2.0564);
System.out.printf("cat =     " + "%11.5f  percent\n", 1232.05);
```

But if say you have

```
int temp1 = 1.02
int temp2 = 12345.01234
```

and you want to convert it to String with the decimal alignment. So you will have

```
a = "DMC       1.02    percent"
b = "POLY  12345.01234 percent"
```

Is there any way to do this other than having a bunch of if statment to check the length?

Comment: You should be able to do something close to this (padding with zero rather than spaces) using [`DecimalFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html).

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```
String.format("%-15s%11.5f percent", "DMC", 1.02);
String.format("%-15s%11.5f percent", "POLY", 12345.01234);
```

It produces:

```
DMC           1.02000 percent
POLY      12345.01234 percent
```

You may need to increase the value of `%-15s` to correctly fit very large numbers.

Comment: @Peter -- The important part that aligns the decimal is the 11.5f.  What you're doing there is allowing for a number of max length 11(including the decimal point).  it's right justified with 5 decimals, so they'll always line up.

Comment: So what Elias said is slightly misleading in that you don't need to increase the 15 for very large numbers, but rather you need to increase the 11 for very large numbers.  the 15 is the padding for the DMC/POLY

Answer (score 0):

You can use String manipulation.

```
String text = "     " + value + "     ";
text = text.substring(text.indexOf('.') - 5, text.indexOf('.') + 5);
```